# RubyOnRails nested/dependent dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with 3 dropdown. For example i have Country, State and City and in the view when the user select Country = US, then in the State dropdown it should populate a list of only US states, and when the state is selected the dropdown only need to bring up the Cities under that state. My Database is setup properly (State have state name and country_id field and City have city name and state_id)

I implemented the following in my view but this bring me all the records regardless of the user selection.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :sector, "Sector" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :nombre, :prompt => false  %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :municipio %>
  <%= f.collection_select :municipio_id, Municipio.all, :id, :nombre, :prompt => false  %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :provincia %>
  <%= f.collection_select :provincia_id, Provincia.all, :id, :nombre, :prompt => false  %>
</div>
```

How can i make these dropdown dependants from each others?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one thing to try would be to add an option so that it becomes:

```
<%= f.label :state%>
<%= f.collection_select :country, :state_id, State.all, :id, :nombre, :prompt => false  %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :city%>
<%= f.collection_select :state, :city_id, City.all, :id, :nombre, :prompt => false  %>
</div>
```

The first three options in collection_select are object, method, collection. So this would be like saying, get the state ids belonging to your instance of country and return the ones that are in the collection returned by State.all.

And make sure that your models are setup appropriately:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Comment: I got undefined method `merge' for :nombre:Symbol when trying to load the page.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I think that what's happening is that rails is automatically setting the first option to what you've named in the f.label method, so when you add in that new option there is one too many (my fault!).  That partially explains why you're getting a list with every state/city/country in it.  The method is asking for the sector_id for everything returned by Sector.all

Comment: This might be more helpful to you.  This example looks very similar to what you're looking for. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:sector, :municipio_id, @provincias, :municipios, :nombre, :id, :nombre) %>. No dice, getting the same error as before. Might be worth mention that this dropdown field is being implemented in another view. Meaning that they all belongs to servicio.rb model.